# python 'module' object has no attribute 'declare_namespace'?

Tags: python, module

I run `python` repl, I can run this:

```
from ipin.rpc.client_factory import client_factory
```

but when I write this to file, then run, I got error as follw:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/parser.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ipin.rpc.client_factory.client_factory import ClientFactory
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ipin/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ipin/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
  File "/tmp/parser.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ipin.rpc.client_factory.client_factory import ClientFactory
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/ipin/rpc/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'declare_namespace'
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback of the exception? Which module is being checked for that name?

Comment: @Blckknght of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your traceback, it looks to me like your code is in a module named `parser.py` which is also a name of a module used within within the `ipin` package. Your module is shadowing the internal module, so when another part of the package tries to get the `declare_namespace` object from `parser`, it fails.

Renaming your program something other than `parser` should work around the issue, but really, it's not your fault. The real fix is for the package to not use relative imports that might be shadowed in this way (Python 3 doesn't allow implicit relative imports any more for exactly this reason).